# MYSQLI SELECT with Limit not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to find the number of rows in a table in the database depending on certain conditions with a limit feature so that i can count the number of rows there are matching the condition after a certain row in the table.

Thus i created my php query:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT u.*, f.* FROM updates U LEFT JOIN friends f ON f.fid = u.userid WHERE f.uid = '$userid'  ORDER BY u.up_id DESC LIMIT $limitID, 9999999");
$nr = $q->num_rows;
```

However even if there are more rows in the database after the `$limitID`, it says there are no rows.
If I try this:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT u.*, f.* FROM updates U LEFT JOIN friends f ON f.fid = u.userid WHERE f.uid = '$userid'  ORDER BY u.up_id DESC LIMIT $limitID");
$nr = $q->num_rows;
```

then it works, but it doesnt count after the `$limitID`. Any udeas?

Answer (score 1):

According yo your *query*, it should be like

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM updates U 
        LEFT JOIN friends f ON f.fid = u.userid WHERE f.uid = ?";
// getting stuff using prepared statements
$row = $res->fetch_row();
$num = $row[0] - $limitID;
```

but I doubt it's really what you need either.

Comment: No its not working either. The problem comes more from the fact that the number of rows isnt equal to the $limitID which comes from the row ID.

Comment: Exactly - that's what I said in my answer. you rather need to make a condition like WHERE someid > $limitID

Comment: Sorted it out, with help from you. I'll post my answer for reference sake

Answer (score -2):

Using what Your Common Sense told me I managed to find an answer to my problem, so here it is:

```
$limitID = $upid;
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM updates u 
LEFT JOIN friends f ON f.fid = u.userid WHERE
(f.uid = '$userid' AND u.up_id > '$limitID')";
$res = $db->query($sql);
$row = $res->fetch_row();
$num = $row[0];
if($num == 0){
    // do nothing
} else {
    echo "<span class='newPosts'>" .$num. " New Post"
          . (($num>1)?'s':' ') . "</span>";
}
```

works perfectly

Comment: you obviously  don't need order by here

Comment: Every time I see "it worked" from a PHP user as a proof to some idea, I feel I wish I never knew that language.

Comment: Its not about it being a proof, its about it doing what I need to do. If you don't like that, don't worry about it, because its not your project. I thank you for the help.